# How to select the certain value in the MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I am using in SQL version MySQL 5.5, I have a problem to get the result in the database. I want to select category = 1 and selected category = 1 data parentid number if is same id number, so parentid under the id number data need to show.

For example below the picture:

[image: output]

Below query is my hard code, how can automatic just know the category is 1 then all the record will get the result follow the if parendid = id.

```
select id, name, parentid, category, category_id 
from filing_code_management 
where category = 1 and (parentid = 76 or id = 76) 
   or id = 76 or id = 2 or id = 1
```

What I've tried, but it doesn't work for me:

```
select id, name, parentid, category, category_id 
from filing_code_management 
where category = 1 or (parentid or id) or id = parentid
```

This is my dbfiddle   https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=785bc009a50aa4c7597510858853865b

Comment: In order to implement this solution you need to use Recursive CTEs. Unfortunately MySQL 5.x does not support them. You would need to upgrade to MySQL 8.x to get a satisfactory solution to this question.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63786567/edit) to more clearly describe what you're trying to do and the problem you're having.

Comment: The OP wants to get all rows with category = `x` (x = 1 in this case); then recursively get all parent rows using `parentid = id` up to the top.